# youtube v3 api, check if Video existing

Tags: php, youtube-api

I've tried to check if a youtube video is online, not private, not deleted etc. I need it for a Video-Blog.

All of the code I've found and tried hadn't worked. I hope you can help me.
I've registered for the new API v3.

My code is as follows, but I always get "Bad Request 400"

```
$theURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=". get_post_meta($post->ID,"wpzoom_post_embed_code", true) ."&key=my_api_key";
//                echo $theURL;
                //$theURL = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=". get_post_meta($post->ID,"wpzoom_post_embed_code", true) ."&format=json";
                $headers = get_headers($theURL);
                print_r ($headers);
                if (substr($headers[0], 9, 3) !== "404") {
                    echo "online";
                } else {
                    echo "offline";
                }
```

Comment: I've managed to get your code to work. What does your $theUrl string look like printed out? A 400 bad request usually means something wrong with a patrameter/toke/filter see here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors

Comment: Output of $theURL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=pAHgB-k-jfg&key=api_key - I didn't get how to use the right parameters

Comment: This is the printet request: (
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
    [1] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [2] => Content-Length: 1419
    [3] => Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 11:27:13 GMT
    [4] => Server: GFE/2.0
)

Comment: sometimes I get a 403 Code

Comment: Again, the URL you supplied worked for me. You are replacing 'api_key' from the URL with your generated API key aren't you? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: I replace it with the key for server-side things,is right?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the thing, i used this code in a loop?

Comment: Yes that is correct, for the sake of testing, try generating a new key making sure that any IP is allowed. Could be that you have reached your limit for this particular API key. Your loop could also be effecting this so take your above snippet of code and test in a simple php file, so you know it works!

Comment: I didn't reached the limits.  I think that the error have to be in my code. Every Page has maximum of 20 videos, that will be checked. I used that in my Wordpress blog, maybe this is my fault? - Generate a new Key fpr Server-Side Applications, same thing

Comment: I think I got the solution. I get everytime the header. Maybe to use the Array what the send give back?

Comment: Well your exact code above works perfectly fine for me, I just need to replace the api key! Give your solution a try sure

Comment: Ahhh your key does not work for me, so it looks like you have used it too much. Perhaps the loop is causing you to overuse the api key. Check your usage allowance in your console https://console.developers.google.com/project

Comment: Got up to 1.000 requests and 800 failed

Comment: It looks like this, the first video is invalid (for testing) and the second is valid - [url=http://abload.de/image.php?img=unbenanntxfs5q.png][img]http://abload.de/thumb/unbenanntxfs5q.png[/img][/url]

Comment: sorry, right link: http://abload.de/img/unbenanntxfs5q.png

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. But I didn't figured it out, how can I display locked Videos as offline. I search in my curl data string for "totalResults": 0,"  cause I fetch at once one ID for video.

Here is my code. - Maybe someone has a better idea to fix this little problem.

```
$theURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "wpzoom_post_embed_code", true) . "&key=my_api_key";
        $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$theURL);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 

    $data =  curl_exec($ch); 
    //var_dump($data); 

        if (strpos($data,'totalResults": 0,') !== false) {
            echo '<span> <img src="link_for_button" alt="online"/> Offline</span><br />';  //echo "<span style='color:red;'>Video Offline</span>";
        } else echo '<span><img src="link_for_button" alt="online"/> Online</span><br />'; //echo "<span style='color:green;'>Video Online</span>";
```